# Should I run large queries on ContentResolver in the main application process?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, android-syncadapter

I currently require a `ContentProvider` built on top of a `SQLite` database for my `SyncService`/`SyncAdapter` that runs in a separate process from my application. The `SyncService` does some small queries and updates to some data. I figured I could use the `ContentProvider` (accessed through `getContentResolver()`) to access/update data throughout my main application as well, instead of directly querying the `SQL` database the provider is built on top of.

Recently though, I have been plagued with `TransactionTooLargeExceptions` in my `SyncAdapter` `(:sync process)` - even though it is only making small queries/updates the the database. However, I make much larger queries with the `ContentProvider` in my application (Main process). Could this be the reasoning behind the buffer getting too large in the `SyncAdapter`? Do both processes share the same `ContentProvider`, and therefore the same Transaction buffer?

If this is the case, it would be wise to NOT use the `ContentProvider` in the main application process, correct? If that isn't the case - what are the pros/cons of using a `ContentProvider` inside the main app at all?